# Event queue in Python

Tags: python, events, computer-science

When writing an event and a handler for that event in python, how do you control the order by which the system inserts your event into the event queue?

Comment: Are you talking about using the `sched` module?

Comment: Perhaps sched can be implemented. I'm looking for a way to execute events one after another dynamically and sequentially.